# Display Selected values in v-select multiple

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-select

I am new in vue js. Using vue2, I have a v-select implemented on my site now, I want to select multiple values and save and show them while editing. But I can't show multiple values properly using :reduce
Here is my code:

```
<v-select name="allowed_extensions"  
:reduce="allowed_extensions => allowed_extensions.value"   
multiple 
:closeOnSelect="false" 
v-model="form.allowed_extensions" 
:options="file_options"  
 v-validate="'required'" > </v-select>
```

In js:

```
data () {
    return {

      isDisabled: false, //Submit Button
      form: {
          maximum_file_size: '',
          allowed_extensions: ''
        },

      be_errors: {},

      // Options
     
      file_options: [
        { label: 'doc',     value: 'doc' },
        { label: 'docx',     value: 'docx' },
        { label: 'pdf',     value: 'pdf'  },
        { label: 'txt',     value: 'txt' },
        { label: 'gif',     value: 'gif' },
        { label: 'png',     value: 'png' },
        { label: 'jpg',     value: 'jpg' },
        { label: 'jpeg',     value: 'jpeg' }
      ]
    }
}
```

IN Mysql DB, sample data saved as : ["doc","txt"]
But when I want to display them in edit, it showing wrongly in a single tag.
[image]
How can I solve this

Comment: what is your current output/result ?

Comment: added output screenshot in question

Comment: how do you initialize them in edit mode

Comment: I guess you saved it as a varchar in MySQL, so it returns as a string when you receive it from database. You need to parse it back to JSON using `JSON.parse(form.allowed_extensions)`